# Fill multiple UIViews with gradient

Tags: swift, uiview, gradient, uicolor

I have a cup with a liquid container, consisting of two UIViews — one for the main body of the liquid, and one for the animated wave on the surface. The liquid container is masked to a cup shape.

[image]

Is there any way I can fill both the primary liquid and wave views with one colour (preferably a gradient) to effectively merge them? Can this be done with another mask?

Comment: have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987883/how-can-i-add-a-gradient-that-spans-two-views

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

- your main body liquid view and the wave view are added as subviews to container view.
- you have added a mask to that container view (liquidContainer)
- then you have added the liquidContainer to another main view where you have the cup as subview as well

[image]

If that's the case, you could trying adding a `CAGradientLayer` to the layer of the container view as sublayer:

```
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

    gradient.startPoint = someStartPoint
    gradient.endPoint = someEndPoint
    gradient.frame = someFrame
    gradient.colors = someColorsArray //note that it uses CGColor if you use UIColor it won't work
    liquidContainerView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

If I misunderstood your view hierarchy, why not try to reproduce this hierarchy in your setup and see if it works.